# Typing a list of lists of strings in Cython

Tags: cython

I have a Cython function that's receiving a list of lists of strings:

```py
cdef cbuild(char*** corpus, int state):
    # corpus is a list of lists of strings
    cdef char** run
    for run in corpus:
        # run is a list of strings
        ...
```

I'd like to be able to type the `corpus` in order to elicit speedups from Cython. The problem is, it's a pretty complex type, and `char***` doesn't seem to work (and thus I have no way of knowing if `char**` for `run` works).

This function is the bottleneck for my Python application, which is why I'm rewriting it in Cython. What can I do to get the most out of Cython by typing these complex objects? Is there some other way I can organise my data to avoid these problems?

Comment: (One of the) issue(s) is that pointers don't carry any information on the size of what they point to. Have you profiled to get an idea of what the slow bit is: Python lists aren't too inefficient; I wonder if it's what's in the loop that's slow rather than the loops themselves

Comment: I'm inexperienced enough that I don't understand the difference between the loop being slow and the contents of the loop being slow. My goal here is to just type everything and see what kind of speedup that gets me. The function is pretty small, thankfully - only ~10 lines - so that's not too difficult. Profiling has indicated that it's this function (and therefore this loop) that is slowing things down, but I wasn't able to get much more detail than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with C++:

```py
from libcpp.vector import vector
from libcpp.string import string

cdef cbuild(vector[vector[string]] corpus, int state):
    cdef vector[string] run
    cdef string word
    for run in corpus:
        for word in run:
            ...
```

Just make sure that `language="c++"` is passed to the Cython compiler (e.g. as a kwarg to `setuptools.Extension`)